# iPad Pro 11" keyboard case stops working when screen is laid flat against the back sleeve

Tags: ipad

i just spent an hour troubleshooting and rebooting my new iPad and then time with support online only to realize it will only work in stand up mode ?

i don't like to stand it up because the angle is way too steep for a tall person.

is there a reason why it stops working as soon the screen is flat against the back of the case ?

[image]

*i tried to post this on discussions.apple.com but it kept giving me the super descriptive "You are not allowed to create or update this content" error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous generation 10.5" has this same limitation. There is a magnetic switch in the bottom edge that prevents the keyboard from activating if it's not in one of the slots on the keyboard case - simply having the connection to the iPad is not sufficient.

Comment: thanks. i  just don't see a point for this requirement...

Comment: i guess that's how they prevent keys being active while in case mode.. but i need a keyboard while the screen is at a lower angle, so will have to return it i guess